# How to get item container (e.g. stackpanel) from listbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have code like this

```
<ListBox x:Name="filterListBox" Height="60">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel x:Name="TargetPanel">
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush />
    </ListBox.Background>
</ListBox>
```

and i get first listbox item with this

```
object item = filterListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
ListBoxItem lbi = item as ListBoxItem;
```

Now I need to get this stackpanel called "TargetPanel" but I don't know how. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a built in way to do this with a simple method call unfortunately. However, it's easy enough. With a few modifications to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example, you can get a particular child of the DataTemplate by `name`:

```
// the call
var item = filterListBox.ItemContainerGenerator
               .ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
var sp = FindVisualChild<StackPanel>(item, "TargetPanel");
// the variable sp should be set to the TargetPanel for the item now
```

The code you'll need to add somewhere (it could be in a "helper" class):

```
using System.Windows.Media;   // for VisualTreeHelper

private static TChildItem FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(DependencyObject obj, 
    string matchName = "") where TChildItem : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is TChildItem)
        {
            // match by name
        var childName = child.GetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty) as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(matchName))
        {
                if (matchName == childName) 
                {
                return (TChildItem)child;
                }
        } 
            else 
            {
                return (TChildItem)child;
            }       
        }
        else
        {
        var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(child, matchName);
        if (childOfChild != null)
        {
            return childOfChild;
        }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```